# HtmlUnit ignore JavaScript errors?

Tags: java, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I'm trying to traverse through a website but on one of their pages I get this error:

```
EcmaError: lineNumber=[671] column=[0] lineSource=[null] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://reservations.besodelsolresort.com/asp/CalendarPopup.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot read property "parentNode" from undefined (https://reservations.besodelsolresort.com/asp/CalendarPopup.js#671)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "parentNode" from undefined (https://reservations.besodelsolresort.com/asp/CalendarPopup.js#671)
```

Is there anyway I can just ignore this error? I don't particularly care if the calendar loads properly.

Comment: solution based on setting final field http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745061/is-it-possible-to-ignore-javascript-exceptions-when-working-with-webdriver-html/35037593#35037593

Answer (score 33):

Alexey's answer is for HttpUnit.  For HtmlUnit the code is similar

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

Comment: How HtmlUnit refers to WebClient ?

Comment: @user12384512 - HtmlUnit has its own WebClient class - `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient`; Also check @jseteny answer below for its usage.

Answer (score 10):

I tried to use Matthews answer and needed to override the newWebClient() method using the following way:

```
    HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true) {
        @Override
        protected WebClient newWebClient(BrowserVersion version) {
            WebClient webClient = super.newWebClient(version);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            return webClient;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following methods of [**HttpUnitOptions**](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/api/com/meterware/httpunit/HttpUnitOptions.html) class:

```
//change the scriptingEnabled flag
static void setScriptingEnabled(boolean scriptingEnabled)

// Determines whether script errors result in exceptions or warning messages.
static void setExceptionsThrownOnScriptError(boolean throwExceptions)
```

Or enclose the problem area in try-catch block -

```
try {
   // code with error

}catch(e) {
   // handle error
}
```

Comment: How does `HttpUnit` refers to `HtmlUnit`? Seems that these are different frameworks...