# How can I avoid JavaScript Errors in Selenium's HtmlUnitDriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, htmlunit, selenium-chromedriver, htmlunit-driver

I'm new to `Selenium` and I'm trying to connect to a site.

```
String url = [url][1]

    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);

    driver.get(url);
```

I'm facing JavaScript errors while executing this line.

I searched few questions and also tried

```
    driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

Still it is generating same problem in `drive.get(url)` line.

I'm unable to find the actual problem here.

Can anyone tell me what is the main problem behind this? 
Is it the page that takes little more time to load? 
Or any other reason?

I've also paste the output text of the problem. here below

```
Nov 23, 2015 5:03:15 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify

WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.

Nov 23, 2015 5:03:17 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify

WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.

Nov 23, 2015 5:03:21 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify

WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: 

TypeError: TypeError: redeclaration of const constructor.

Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'

System info: host: 'User-PC', ip: '192.168.1.66', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.
version: '1.8.0_40'

Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:554)
```

Comment: Please provide the URL, so others can check. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AhmedAshour
link url =https://www.kcmo.org/Ads/faces/AdSearch.jspx?_afrWindowMode=0&_afrLoop=1001263381394588&_adf.ctrl-state=kzoykemys_14

Comment: You can't avoid javascript errors, you could turn it off in case you don't need javascript on the page to work properly or you can set the throwexceptiononscripterror (not sure about the correct name, has been a while I used it last) to false to just ignore all javascript errors. This might just lead to the application not working properly. Alternatively take a look at PhantomJS which has better javascript support

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HtmlUnit ignore JavaScript errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294707/htmlunit-ignore-javascript-errors)