# HtmlUnit - Cannot call method "replace" of undefined

Tags: javascript, java, exception, htmlunit

I have only this code:

```
package main;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
*
* @author Pablis
*/
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = client.getPage(
                "http://www.aa2000.com.ar/");
        System.out.println(page.asXml());
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
run:
Jun 07, 2016 2:52:04 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[49] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval)] message=[TypeError: Cannot call method "replace" of undefined (http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval)#49)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "replace" of undefined (http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval)#49)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:904)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:786)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:762)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:990)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:352)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:238)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:257)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:772)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:729)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1209)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1111)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:207)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:337)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3137)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2100)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:927)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:506)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:459)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:979)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:241)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:187)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:269)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:157)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:511)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:385)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:303)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:450)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:435)
    at main.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:15)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "replace" of undefined (http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval)#49)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3917)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3901)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3926)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3942)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefCallError(ScriptRuntime.java:3958)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2390)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2384)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1342)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.evalSpecial(ScriptRuntime.java:2648)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.callSpecial(ScriptRuntime.java:2510)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.doCallSpecial(Interpreter.java:2385)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1380)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:413)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:252)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:777)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:889)
    ... 32 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "replace" of undefined (http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval)#49)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3917)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3901)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3926)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3942)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefCallError(ScriptRuntime.java:3958)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2390)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2384)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1342)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.ZS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.sS(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):49)
    at script.S_(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):51)
    at script.J_(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):52)
    at script.__(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):52)
    at script(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):86)
    at script(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):46)
    at script(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval):1)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.evalSpecial(ScriptRuntime.java:2648)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.callSpecial(ScriptRuntime.java:2510)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.doCallSpecial(Interpreter.java:2385)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1380)
    at script.kRKh(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7:1)
    at script(http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7:1)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:413)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:252)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:777)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:889)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:786)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:762)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:990)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:352)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:238)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:257)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:772)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:729)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1209)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1111)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:207)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:337)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3137)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2100)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:927)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:506)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:459)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:979)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:241)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:187)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:269)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:157)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:511)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:385)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:303)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:450)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:435)
    at main.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:15)
======= EXCEPTION END ========
C:\Users\Pablis\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

I tried suppresing the errors by setting the webclient to not throw exceptions, but it just compiles and the page is never shown.

I'm using the lastets version of HTMLUNIT. I'm out of ideas.

Nobody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like this aa2000 page is totally broken, e.g. JS file like `http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js` is served with HTML header and `html/text` MIME:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Anyway, at the beginning of the exception you have this line:

```
EcmaError: lineNumber=[49] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval)] message=[TypeError: Cannot call method "replace" of undefined (http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7#1(eval)#49)]
```

It tells you that at line 49, in file `http://www.aa2000.com.ar/TSPD/08baef9ac4ab20008be96cfea948af54375f925c87d7a1a4150c900b233e6129b77bd7f2be0c1026?type=7` is an JS error: `TypeError: Cannot call method "replace" of undefined`.

You can either fix this error, or you can force CoreJS to ignore all JS errors: [HtmlUnit ignore JavaScript errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294707/htmlunit-ignore-javascript-errors) but then page may not work as you expect...

Comment: Thanks. I'm just using HtmlUnit, so I dont know much about Javascript, but my guess was just that. They did something to the webpage and know I dont know how to query it without HtmlUnit. I did disable the exceptions for javascript, but the program just compiles and no page content is fetched.